# How to add a where clause to Sequelize functions?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use aggregate functions to extract multiple different sums from a table using multiple different where clauses.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
model.findAll({
  attributes:[
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('columnA')), 'sumA1'], // need to add where:{condition1}
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('columnB')), 'sumB1'], // need to add where:{condition1}
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('columnA')), 'sumA2'], // need to add where:{condition2}
    [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('columnB')), 'sumB2'], // need to add where:{condition2}
    ...
  ]
)}
```

So far I've managed to make this work using Promise.all and making different calls to the database for each "where clause condition" or getting all data from the table and using node to calculate the sums. Is there a better way of doing this using sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer the literal way then it would be simple with subquery where

```
model.findAll({
  limit: 1,
  attributes:[
    [sequelize.literal(`(select sum(columnA) from table where date = '2021-01-05')`), 'testSum'],
    ...and so on
  ]
})
```

you see from basic SQL concept the thing you need to perform is subquery or the over() clause using the window in either cases you need have a raw query first and then try to convert it over to sequelize syntax.

Comment: I'm getting an error "syntax error at or near "AS". The raw sql using this method looks like: "SELECT sum(columnA) from table where condition = cond1 AS "sumA1" FROM "table" AS "table";"

Comment: can you provide whole error and the sequlize query you have used for the same?

Comment: The whole error is too long to fit in a comment so I've made a pastebin. I'm guessing the problem is because I'm getting two 'AS' statements in my call. https://pastebin.com/svmJmnb7

Comment: sql: `SELECT sum(columnA) from tables where date = '2021-01-05' AS "testSum" FROM "tables" AS "table";`,

This query at SQL is incorrect

Comment: check the updated answer once!

Comment: I'm using your updated answer and now it's returning an array equal to the amount of rows in the SQL table, each element in the returning array contains the same object of { testSum1: 123, testSum2: 123, ...etc}. I have added "limit: 1" to the sequelize call and I am now getting the expected return value. I will accept your answer and added an edit fixing two small syntax errors. Thank you!